# CUDA same function for CPU and GPU

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpgpu

In order to call the same function from host code and GPU kernel, Do I have to keep the two copies of the same function as below:

```
int sum(int a, int b){
return a+b;
}

__device int sumGPU(int a, int b){
return a+b;
}
```

Or is there any technique to keep/manage a single copy of the function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just have to add the `__host__` keyword to be able to call call a function from host or device.

```
__host__ __device__ int sum(int a, int b){
  return a+b;
}
```